# Hide div when other div is showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a page with 3 buttons, each opening a different div-element. What I want, is to **show just one div at the time**. So when one div is opened, the other div should close.

I managed to create the buttons each opening a different div-element. But I cannot figure out a way to automatically close the div when other div is opened.

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
var button3 = document.getElementById("button3");
var content1 = document.getElementById("content1");
var content2 = document.getElementById("content2");
var content3 = document.getElementById("content3");
content1.style.display = "none";
content2.style.display = "none";
content3.style.display = "none";
button1.addEventListener("click", showContent1);
button2.addEventListener("click", showContent2);
button3.addEventListener("click", showContent3);

function showContent1() {
  if (content1.style.display !== "none") {
    content1.style.display = "none"
  } else {
    content1.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function showContent2() {
  if (content2.style.display !== "none") {
    content2.style.display = "none"
  } else {
    content2.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function showContent3() {
  if (content3.style.display !== "none") {
    content3.style.display = "none"
  } else {
    content3.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#button1,
#button2,
#button3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#content1,
#content2,
#content3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="button1">button 1</div>
<div id="button2">button 2</div>
<div id="button3">button 3</div>
<div id="content1">content 1</div>
<div id="content2">content 2</div>
<div id="content3">content 3</div>
```

Comment: Does the jQuery tag imply that you would accept a jQuery solution? If not, then it should be removed.

Comment: Taken at face value, all you need to do is after you do `content1.style.display = "block";` call `content2.style.display = "none";` and the same for `content3`. It's that simple. Having said that, using ids with running numbers and thus having to create duplicate code like this is bad practice.

Comment: Here's a jQuery solution: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8prgjoea/

Answer (score 6):

You can cut down your code to something like this:

```
$("[id^=button]").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("button", "")
  $("#content" + id).toggle();
});
```

The code below will only allow 1 div to show at the time.

```
$("[id^=button]").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("button", "");
  $("[id^=content]").hide()
  $("#content" + id).show();
});
```

Here we are using the `^` to say that we want all element starting with `button` to trigger the click event.

**Demo**

```js
$("[id^=button]").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("button", "")
  $("#content" + id).toggle();
});
```

```css
#button1,
#button2,
#button3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#content1,
#content2,
#content3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button1">button 1</div>
<div id="button2">button 2</div>
<div id="button3">button 3</div>
<div id="content1">content 1</div>
<div id="content2">content 2</div>
<div id="content3">content 3</div>
```

Comment: Also jQuery on a javascript question. OP has added it in the tags but doesn't use it.

Comment: @Wimanicesir if he's adding jQuery, then I assume he accepts jQuery solutions.

Comment: Thank you for providing simple jQuery solution! I wanted to understand how to achieve this just with JavaScript, but I might end up using this solution instead.

Comment: Running the code snippet and clicking all the button once, shows/opens all the div element.

Comment: @NaveenKumarV I was told by a user(who has deleted hes comment now) that op wanted this effect.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a canonical way to do this.

Please study and look at where I delegate and have added classes

Use toggle() in the jQuery example to open AND close on click

jQuery:

```js
$(".button").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".content").hide(); 
  $("#" + $(this).data("id")).show(); // or .toggle()
});
```

```css
.button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button" data-id="content1">button 1</div>
<div class="button" data-id="content2">button 2</div>
<div class="button" data-id="content3">button 3</div>
<div class="content" id="content1">content 1</div>
<div class="content" id="content2">content 2</div>
<div class="content" id="content3">content 3</div>
```

Vanilla JS

```js
document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches(".button")) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".content").forEach(function(div) { // a simple for loop is needed for older IE
      div.style.display = "none";
    });
    // Here I just show. If you want to toggle, you could use classList.toggle
    document.getElementById(tgt.getAttribute("data-id")).style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
.button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div class="button" data-id="content1">button 1</div>
  <div class="button" data-id="content2">button 2</div>
  <div class="button" data-id="content3">button 3</div>
</div>
<div class="content" id="content1">content 1</div>
<div class="content" id="content2">content 2</div>
<div class="content" id="content3">content 3</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can even create a tab system without any javascript *at all*, using the radio button css trick.

If a radio button is checked, then the next div is displayed, using the [sibling selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp): `~`.

```css
input{
  display: none;
}

label{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

label:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.display{
  display: none;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ .display{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <label for="div1">Show div 1</label>
  <label for="div2">Show div 2</label>
  <label for="div3">Show div 3</label>
</section>

<section>
  <input type="radio" id="div1" name="tab-nav" checked />
  <div class="display">
    Text from div 1.
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <input type="radio" id="div2" name="tab-nav" />
  <div class="display">
    Text from div 2. It's cool.
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <input type="radio" id="div3" name="tab-nav" />
  <div class="display">
    Text from div 3. Definitely a cool css trick.
  </div>
</section>
```

*Here's another [src](https://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/) and it's [demo](https://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/radio.php).*

Answer (score 1):

```js
//find all buttons
document.querySelectorAll("button[data-target]").forEach(el => {
  //put a click event on each button
  el.addEventListener("click", ev => {
    //when clicked, hide all divs
    let divs = document.getElementsByClassName("my-div");
    for (let div of divs) { 
      div.style = "display: none;"; 
    }
    
    //then show the div that this button should be showing
    //by grabbing it's id from the data-target attribute and setting it's style
    document.getElementById(el.getAttribute("data-target")).style = "display: block;";
  });
});
```

```css
.my-div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button data-target="div1">div1</button>
<button data-target="div2">div2</button>
<button data-target="div3">div3</button>

<div class="my-div" id="div1">content 1</div>
<div class="my-div" id="div2">content 2</div>
<div class="my-div" id="div3">content 3</div>
```

Comment: `style.display = "block"` is less intrusive

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Accordion](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp), if that is what you are ultimately trying to achieve.

Remove the condition in the button's click event if you do not want to hide the same content on second click.

**SOLUTION:**

```
button1.addEventListener("click", () => activeDiv = (activeDiv === "content1") ? "": "content1");
button2.addEventListener("click", () => activeDiv = (activeDiv === "content2") ? "": "content2");
button3.addEventListener("click", () => activeDiv = (activeDiv === "content3") ? "": "content3");
button1.addEventListener("click", openDivGroup);
button2.addEventListener("click", openDivGroup);
button3.addEventListener("click", openDivGroup);

var activeDiv = '';
function openDivGroup ($event) {
    var contentIdArray = jQuery ("[id^=content]");
    for (var i = 0; i < contentIdArray.length; i++) {
        if (activeDiv === contentIdArray[i].id) contentIdArray[i].style.display = 'block';
        else contentIdArray[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
 #button1,
 #button2,
 #button3 {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: lightblue;
   margin: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

 #content1,
 #content2,
 #content3 {
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   background: blue;
   color: white;
   margin: 5px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="button1">button 1</div>
<div id="button2">button 2</div>
<div id="button3">button 3</div>
<div id="content1">content 1</div>
<div id="content2">content 2</div>
<div id="content3">content 3</div>

<script>
 var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
 var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
 var button3 = document.getElementById("button3");
 var content1 = document.getElementById("content1");
 var content2 = document.getElementById("content2");
 var content3 = document.getElementById("content3");
 content1.style.display = "none";
 content2.style.display = "none";
 content3.style.display = "none";
 button1.addEventListener("click", () => activeDiv = (activeDiv === "content1") ? "": "content1");
 button2.addEventListener("click", () => activeDiv = (activeDiv === "content2") ? "": "content2");
 button3.addEventListener("click", () => activeDiv = (activeDiv === "content3") ? "": "content3");
 button1.addEventListener("click", openDivGroup);
 button2.addEventListener("click", openDivGroup);
 button3.addEventListener("click", openDivGroup);

 var activeDiv = '';
 function openDivGroup ($event) {
  var contentIdArray = jQuery ("[id^=content]");
  for (var i = 0; i < contentIdArray.length; i++) {
   if (activeDiv === contentIdArray[i].id) contentIdArray[i].style.display = 'block';
   else contentIdArray[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
 }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: DRY: Don't repeat yourself